# Ftp site browsing in mobile phones

Tags: android, iphone, ipad, bada

Is there a way to allow ftp browsing in mobile phones.

ftp://ipaddress
  or
  ftp://username:password@ipaddress

both are not working in mobile phones.

please help me

Comment: Are you trying to do it in the browser?

Comment: Search the relevant app stores for the keyword "FTP". Note that working with files in general tends to be stunted on mobile platforms - i. e. when you download a PDF file with a FTP client, you cannot easily pass that file to a PDF reader.

Comment: so sorry for very late response @Waynn Lue yes i am trying to do it from the browser

Comment: Then it's not a programming question, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Opera Mobile can do that for you on the Android platform.

Answer (score 0):

You need an FTP client library, such as [Apache's FTPClient library](https://commons.apache.org/net/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html). Download that and import the library and you should be on your way!

Comment: actually i want to browse the site from the browser it's not about transferring files through ftp clients. In system it is working if we give like  ftp://username:password@ipaddress